# MVC4 ToList() show first few records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just learning how to use .net and mvc4 and I have a problem. I have no idea how to show only the first 5(or any number) rows in a table. This is how I'm currently sending my information to the view.

```
public ActionResult ActiveCampaigns()
{
    var campaigns = db.ActiveCampaigns.ToList();
    return View(campaigns);
}
```

Thanks :)

Update:
Thanks for the quick responses! So simple!

```
db.ActiveCampaigns.Take(5).ToList()
```

I searched high and low and couldn't find this, my google-fu must be off. Thanks again!

Comment: `db.ActiveCampaigns.Take(5).ToList()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic approach would be

```
 var campaigns = db.ActiveCampaigns.Take(5).ToList();
```

But depending on what type of Context `db` is, this might fail. `Skip()` and `Take()` are not always available or allowed on all IEnumrable-derived interfaces. In that case read the error. Usually you can fix it in two ways:

```
 var campaigns = db.ActiveCampaigns.ToList().Take(5);  // expensive with many Campaigns
```

or, when you have a convenient sort-criterium:

```
 var campaigns = db.ActiveCampaigns.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: What would be the more advanced approach? If you don't mind me asking? This worked perfectly, thankyou :)

Comment: Already edited with variations. Will you be needing Skip (Paging) as well or always just the first few ?

Comment: I was going to just take the 5 latest rows. It seems like your latter variation should do that perfectly?

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

```
public ActionResult ActiveCampaigns()
{
    var campaigns = db.ActiveCampaigns.Take(5).ToList();
    return View(campaigns);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're interested in paging, in which case, you'd need to use the Skip() method, also:

```
var campaigns = db.ActiveCampaigns.Skip(5).Take(5).ToList();
```

would get you page 2. Obviously, you're going to want to use a formula to handle which page to display:

```
var campaigns = db.ActiveCampaigns.Skip((page-1) * 5).Take(5).ToList();
```